# Implementing React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement React router but only a white window appears in the browser.
I have tried many things, but every time I try to implement React Router, only a white window . And wherein
"webpack compiled successfully "

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What versions of React and `react-router-dom` (*it looks like `react-router-dom@5`*) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            {" "}
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the old version! Thanks, this is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `react-router-dom@6`  you should replace `Switch` with `Routes`

Imports should look like this :

```
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

then use it like this :

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Component />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Note that also when using it , replace `useHistory` with `useNavigate`

For more information on how to migrate to V6  read this : https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v6